# Criar um select dentro de outro select para selecionar os dez melhores valores de cada mês

Tags: mysql, select, dbeaver

Eu estou tentando pegar os 10 melhores valores de cada mês, já procurei artigo aqui, mas nenhum me ajudou até agora, tentei fazer vários subquery, mas foi quase a mesma coisa de pegar tabela 1 e combinar cada valor com ela mesma.
Teria como fazer algo do tipo: `SELECT (SELECT NOME, TOTAL FROM TB1 WHERE MES = '2016-01-01') AS 'JAN',(SELECT NOME, TOTAL FROM TB1 WHERE MES = '2016-02-01') AS 'FEV' ... (SELECT NOME, TOTAL FROM TB1 WHERE MES = '2016-12-01') AS 'DEZ' FROM TB1`?

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que você tenha uma tabela com a seguinte estrutura:

```
+-------+----------+
| CAMPO | TIPO     |
+-------+----------+
| ID    | NUMERIC  |
| NOME  | VARCHAR  |
| TOTAL | NUMERIC  |
| MES   | DATE     |
+-------+----------+
```

Você poderia fazer algo como:

```sql
WITH DADOS AS (
    SELECT ID, 
           NOME,
           TOTAL,
           EXTRACT(MONTH FROM MES) MES,
           EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MES) ANO,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM MES) ORDER BY TOTAL DESC) RANKING
    FROM TABELA1
)
SELECT ID,
       NOME, 
       TOTAL,
       MES,
       ANO
FROM DADOS
WHERE RANKING < 11
```

### Explicação

Neste caso nós construímos uma relação usando o [WITH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), nesta relação nós temos o `ID`, `NOME`, valor `TOTAL`, `MES`, `ANO` e `RANKING`.

Para construir o RANKING nós usamos a função [RANK](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-rank-function/), e especificamos uma partição, dentro de uma partição a contagem é reiniciada para cada partição, no nosso caso usamos o `ANO_MES` como partição e ordenamos os valores de forma decrescente (do maior para o menor).

Isso nos dá uma relação que fica com esta estrutura.

```
+-------+----------+
| CAMPO | TIPO     |
+-------+----------+
| ID    | NUMERIC  |
| NOME  | VARCHAR  |
| TOTAL | NUMERIC  |
| MES   | NUMERIC  |
| ANO   | NUMERIC  |
| RANK  | NUMERIC  |
+-------+----------+
```

Uma vez munidos desta relação nós só fizemos um `select`, limitando o RANK aos 10 primeiros.

Como temos uma coluna para o `MES` e outra para o `ANO` você pode fazer uma filtragem com facilidade.

### Considerações.

Esta abordagem não retorna cada mês como uma coluna, para isso se você quiser fazer isso, uma possibilidade é selecionar várias vezes a relação dados, uma para cada mês e filtrando o mês de cada uma na clausula `WHERE`.